# C: How to compare two consecutive nodes in linked list?

Tags: c

For example, the first node contains the letter 'e' and the second node contains the letter 'f', how to compare if these nodes are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
struct Node {
    char data; // contains either 'e' or 'f'
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node one, two; // assume one contains data 'e' and two contains data 'f'
```

What you want is the following:

```
if(strncmp(&one.data, &two.data, 1) == 0) 
{
        printf("equal\n");      
} 
else 
{
        printf("not equal\n");  
};
```